# Observer Pattern Class (JAVA)

Tags: java

I'm stuck on this assignment. I'm given an abstract Observer class with only 1 constructor in it, a constructor with parameters/arguments. (refer below)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    PairOfNumbers numbers1 = new PairOfNumbers();            
    PairOfNumbers numbers2 = new PairOfNumbers();        
    SumObserver sum = new SumObserver(numbers1);        
    ProductObserver prod = new ProductObserver(numbers2);    
    MultiSubjectObserver m = new MultiSubjectObserver();
    m.addSubject(numbers1);
    m.addSubject(numbers2);        
    numbers1.setNumbers(20, 10);
    numbers2.setNumbers(-10, 15);       
}    


class Subject {
    private List<Observer> observers=new ArrayList<Observer>();
    public void attachObserver(Observer observer) {
    this.observers.add(observer);
    }
    public void detachObserver(Observer observer) {
        this.observers.remove(observer);
    }
    public void notifyObservers() {
    for (Observer observer: this.observers)
        observer.update(this);
    }
}   

class PairOfNumbers extends Subject {
    private double number1, number2;
    public double getNumber1() { return this.number1; }
    public double getNumber2() { return this.number2; }
    public void setNumbers(double d1, double d2) {
    this.number1=d1; this.number2=d2;
    this.notifyObservers();  // don't forget to do this!
    }
} 

abstract class Observer {
    public Observer(Subject subject) {
    subject.attachObserver(this);
}

abstract public void update(Subject subject);
}

class SumObserver extends Observer {
    public SumObserver(PairOfNumbers pair) {
    super(pair);
    }
    public void update(Subject subject) {
    PairOfNumbers numbers=(PairOfNumbers)subject;
    System.out.println("New sum is: "+(numbers.getNumber1()+numbers.getNumber2()));
    }
}

class ProductObserver extends Observer {
    public ProductObserver(PairOfNumbers pair) {
        super(pair);        
    }
    public void update(Subject subject) {
   PairOfNumbers numbers=(PairOfNumbers)subject;
   System.out.println("New product is: "+(numbers.getNumber1()*numbers.getNumber2()));
    }
}
```

Okay, now I'm suppose to create another class which inherits from the above class.

```
class MultiSubjectObserver extends Observer{
    public MultiSubjectObserver(PairOfNumbers pair){
        super(pair);
    }   

    public void addSubject(PairOfNumbers pair){
        pair.attachObserver(this);
    }

    public void update(Subject subject){
        PairOfNumbers numbers=(PairOfNumbers)subject;
        System.out.println("MultiSubjectObserver activated with numbers: " +    (numbers.getNumber1())+", "+(numbers.getNumber2()));
    }        
}
```

Is there a way to create a constructor inside the MSO Class which requires no parameter/argument? For example

```
public MultiSubjectObserver(){
    //enter code here 
}
```

Please guide me on this one. Had been thinking for days. Thanks in advance! :D

The instruction is to: Modify the source code to handle any number of Subject objects per Observer.

**Expected output:**

```
New sum is: 30.0 
MultiSubjectObserver activated with numbers: 20.0, 10.0 
New product is: -150.0 
MultiSubjectObserver activated with numbers: -10.0, 15.0
```

Comment: Yes, if you also give `Observer` a no-argument constructor.

Comment: @immibis: not absolutely necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this, create a no-arg child class, but you still must call the arg-needing super constructor within the child constructor.

This:

```
class Child extends Super {
   public Child() {
      super(args_are_needed);
   }
}
```

The tricky part would be -- what to pass into the super constructor in this default case? In your case this *could* be:

```
public MultiSubjectObserver(){
    super(null);
}
```

**Caveat:** and this will lead to a NullPointerException when the super's constructor is called, due to the line, `subject.attachObserver(this);`, so no, you can't do this.

A better solution: make sure that MultiSubjectObserver does ***not*** extend from Observer!

Perhaps something like:

```
class MultiSubjectObserver {
   private List<Observer> observerList = new ArrayList<Observer>();

   public void addSubject(PairOfNumbers numbers1) {
      observerList.add(new InnerObserver(numbers1));
   }

   private class InnerObserver extends Observer {
      public InnerObserver(Subject subject) {
         super(subject);
      }

      @Override
      public void update(Subject subject) {
         System.out.println("From multi-observer: " + subject);
      }
   }    
}
```

But for this to work, you'd have to give PairOfNumbers a decent toString method, perhaps,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return String.format("[%.4f, %.4f]", number1, number2);
}
```

---

**Edit**
Based on the output:

```
class MultiSubjectObserver {
   private static final String FORMAT_STRING = "MultiSubjectObserver activated with numbers: %.1f, %.1f%n";
   private List<Observer> observerList = new ArrayList<Observer>();

   public void addSubject(PairOfNumbers numbers1) {
      observerList.add(new InnerObserver(numbers1));
   }

   private class InnerObserver extends Observer {
      public InnerObserver(Subject subject) {
         super(subject);
      }

      @Override
      public void update(Subject subject) {
         System.out.printf(FORMAT_STRING, ((PairOfNumbers)subject).getNumber1(),  ((PairOfNumbers)subject).getNumber1());
      }
   }
}
```

Although that casting is a bit skanky. I like the toString() version **much** better.

Comment: @user3774597: note the caveat on the bottom of my answer. Why do you feel that you need a no-arg constructor for the child class?

Comment: Ouwh, that's cause in my Main method, the given constructor is `MultiSubjectObserver m = new MultiSubjectObserver();` and I'm not allowed to change it.

Comment: With code as posted, calling `super(null)` will give a very quick `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, yes. That's what I'm getting right now. Can I know what does that mean?

Comment: @user3774597 are you also required to not change Observer? If you can change Observer, then just delete its constructor (and the one in MultiSubjectObserver)

Comment: @user3774597: it means that you can't pass in null into the super's constructor, that this won't fly.

Comment: Yeah not allowed to change anything from the Observer class.

Comment: I wonder if you're interpreting the instructions wrong. Consider posting them all, and all the code.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change anything. I can just do with the MSO class.

Comment: @user3774597: the solution is to make sure that MultiSubjectObserver does ***not*** extend from Observer!

Comment: But if I don't extend from Observer, I can't do `.attachObserver()` in my `addSubject();` method. Or is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Yeen: see edit. You still haven't posted the actual instructions

Comment: Already added Instruction and expected Output. Please see edit.

Comment: I'm still new to this Observer pattern. Can you please explain to me what it's actually happening? And is it able to handle any number of Subject objects per Observer? And what is the difference between your 2nd solution and the 3rd solution? They give the same output though. Please further advise. Thanks